# Can't get sandbox account to post

Tags: paypal, sandbox

A link on PayPal HELP sent me to this site. Not sure of the relationship if any, with PayPal.

Getting this error when using sandbox:

Sandbox error message:

```
"PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem."
```

We use a custom `ColdFusion` shopping cart for our ecommerce site. The form we use works fine for our live, actual payment to PayPal. However, when we add the sandbox part of the URL for testing, we receive the following error message from PayPal:
“PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.”

I have both the personal and business accounts set up on the developer sites and am using the business account on sandbox form.. That seemed to go okay But that’s as far as I got. Once that was done there was no guide I could find to suggest what to do next.
I’ve checked my developer account activity and history and there is none.

I continue to get this error also: “We’re sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.” It’s at this URL:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

[paypal sandbox merchant account error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174859/paypal-sandbox-merchant-account-error)

At the URL above, the forum suggestion stated: “ *.. click the link for sandbox accounts on the left*” of the Applications Tab. But there is nothing there indicating “sandbox account” on the left side or anywhere.

I’d really like to see an example of a sandbox paypal form. There is a suggestion that this be used:
I have no idea how that should be incorporated. The question mark suggests a url, but where, in the form `POST`. Again, and example might clear all this up. Can’t find one. Or like this:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=staff@domain.com.

I guess I need to “create a preconfigured test seller account.” But where? How?  Just a big circle.

I’ve read other examples from others here in this forum but the suggestions don’t always seem to match up with the actual page, perhaps paypay developer site changed. So  confusing. Round and round.

Obviously, everything else is working so we have the correct setup to charge but something must be wrong with the sandbox account. We have both business and personal accounts set up but the error remains. I’ve spent two hours researching but cannot find a clue to what the problem may be. The massive amount of data on PayPal is no help I’ve yet been able to find.

We’d use the standard Buy Now buttons but they have built in payment amounts. Our payment amounts change dynamically so we need to use a variable in the form of the payment amount so that’s why we decided to use a custom form.

I would ask that someone point me to an example of the basic html form looks like and the requirements of that form (allowing custom price amounts based on a variable amount) to send to PayPal sandbox. I imagine it’s not the form but something else because  we must have that form correct or it would not work when sending an actual charge (with the sandbox of the form post removed).

So, more importantly, what might be wrong in the sandbox developer setup? There seems to be no way to test the accuracy of the setup on PayPal developer site, unless I’ve missed it somewhere. I’m a ColdFusion programmer and developer but this is too confusing. Obviously I’m not that great of a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of the redirect to Sandbox.PayPal.com:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=staff@domain.com

You were just missing the `cmd` variable and value. You can pop your `amount` value in there and the `item_name`. If you want to see the actual HTML form I can drop one in here for you.

Here is a list of variables for PayPal Standard you can use:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/

To create a Sandbox account you'll need to sign into Developer.PayPal.com, click on "Applications", then go to the "Sandbox accounts" section. You can create a new account there.