# Check email is valid paypal account then send money from merchant account?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How to send money from **merchant account** to another Paypal account before that check whether the email provided is valid or not?

Comment: Not sure if this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174859/paypal-sandbox-merchant-account-error?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) API operation lets you determine whether the specified PayPal account's status is verified or unverified.